# Is $\sin(e^x-200^{\sin x})$ integrable on $[0,1)$?

Tags: real-analysis, integration

I plotted the graph and was able to compute the integral so I know it must be integrable. But I am curious on how someone would prove that this function is integrable without using a computer. That is:

> Is $\sin(e^x-200^{\sin x})$ integrable on $[0,1)$?

Before using a computer I knew it was going to oscillate from 1 to -1 because the sine function oscillates between those two values. But how do I proceed from there?

Comment: Well $\sin(e^x-200^{ \sin(x) })$ is continuous on $[0,1)$, so it is integrable on that interval.

Comment: The definiton of Riemann integrable requires a closed interval.

Answer (score 2):

Composition, sum, product of continuous functions are continuous.

If a function is continuous on a closed interval $[a,b]$, then it is integrable on $[a,b]$ (thus on $[a,b)$ ).

So, you just need to show that your function is continuous on $[0,1]$.